# Create a two column layout with skeleton framework?

Tags: skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am new to Skeleton framework and am trying to build a two column layout for a blog project. So far this is what I have:

```
<section class="list-posts">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="nine columns posts">
              [NINE COLUMNS]
          </div><!--nine columns-->

          <div class="three columns aside">
            [ASIDE] 
            [/ASIDE]
          </div>
      </div><!--row-->
  </div>
```

but as more columns are added to the .posts class the aside collapses. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem, but if you are trying to nest columns you need to put a row div within the nine columns, and end the row(s) for every twelve columns.

If this is not the case, could you please provide a more specific clarification of your problem with a link or image.

Answer (score 0):

Well after waiting for some hours without getting any help, i decided to get my hands dirty, this is what i did

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!--LIST ALL THE POSTS HERE-->
            <div class="twelve columns">
                <div class='twelve'>
                   <div class='row single-entry'>
                      <div class='six columns'>
                         ...
                      </div>
                      <div class='six columns'>
                       ...
                      </div>
                      </div><!--row-->
            </div><!--twelve-->
        </div><!--row-->

        <!-- ASIDE-->
        <div class="four columns aside border-between">
              <div class="row ">
                  <div class="twelve columns">
                    <div class="twelve">
                        <h4 class="standing">Recommendations</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="twelve columns recommended-articles">
                        <div class="three columns">
                          <img src="images/footer.png" class="u-max-full-width">
                        </div>
                        <div class="nine columns recommended-articles-details">
                            <h6 class="article-title">4 top SEO trends for 2017</h6>
                            <p class="author_name">Joel Orok</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </section>
```